# Bulk Find and Replace from a Master List in Google Sheets

Tags: database, google-sheets, find-replace

I have a spreadsheet in Google Sheets. We currently pulled it from Ooyala to run QA. We are trying to eliminate manual/human QA, and properly format many different values. An example of a row is

```
Header Row
Hello
hello
Yes
yes
Bye
bye
```

Is there a way to write a script that targets a column, for example Header Row, and then finds and replaces an entire master list of values? For example, somehow loading in a master doc that replaces all instances of hello with Hello and yes with Yes in one full swoop? Would also be willing to try R or some other platform.

Comment: Why are you using the [excel] tag on this [google-sheets] question?

Comment: Do you prefer it to be in spreadsheets? Is a formula and copypasting results acceptable?

Comment: Hi @RobinGertenbach, as automated as possible would be the best since we have a lot of data. But any formula would be better than nothing, at this point. Currently we're doing it 100% manually.

Answer (score 2):

If the example column is column A you can put in a free column:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A), UPPER(LEFT(A2:A,1)) & RIGHT(A2:A, LEN(A2:A) - 1), ""))
```

And then copy paste-values the resulting column into column A.

Answer (score 0):

You can just combine the `PROPER` function along with arrayformula and a condition to check for text:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISTEXT(A:A),PROPER(A:A),))
```

[image]

or if you want the final list of values to be unique you can also do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(IF(ISTEXT(A:A),PROPER(A:A),)))
```

[image]